# Getting an error on trying to execute a golang program from a python script

Tags: python, go, mergesort

I'm programming a performance comparison between C++ and GoLang to get data to perform a statistical analysis and I created a Python script to take all data and execute by itself both programs. With C++ I have no problems and the execution works properly, but in go I get this error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.panic(0x44d600, 0x4b9897)
    /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:266 +0xb6
main.merge(0xc210047000, 0x9, 0x10, 0x8, 0x8, ...)
    /windows/DATA/FIB/PE/B7_PLSpeed/nlogn.go:13 +0x22c
main.mergesort(0xc210047000, 0x9, 0x10, 0x8, 0x9)
    /windows/DATA/FIB/PE/B7_PLSpeed/nlogn.go:43 +0xec
main.mergesort(0xc210047000, 0x9, 0x10, 0x5, 0x9)
    /windows/DATA/FIB/PE/B7_PLSpeed/nlogn.go:42 +0xac
main.mergesort(0xc210047000, 0x9, 0x10, 0x0, 0x9)
    /windows/DATA/FIB/PE/B7_PLSpeed/nlogn.go:42 +0xac
main.main()
    /windows/DATA/FIB/PE/B7_PLSpeed/nlogn.go:54 +0x1c1
```

If someone can help me I'd be very pleased!
I'll leave here my Python script and Go source code.

Python:

```
import time
import random
from subprocess import call
from sys import argv


def usage():
    print("Usage: " + argv[0] + " <Binary1> <Binary2> <n elements> <#executions>")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(argv) != 5:
        usage()
    else:
        program1 = argv[1]
        program2 = argv[2]
        n = int(argv[3])
        executions = int(argv[4])

        for x in range(0, executions):
            command = ['']
            # 32-bit range vector(n) random generator
            for y in range(0, n-1):
                command.append(str(random.randint(-2147473648, 2147473647)))

            if(random.choice((True, False))):
                program1, program2 = program2, program1

            # Program1
            command[0] = './' + program1
            pre = time.time()
            call(command)
            post = time.time()
            f = open(program1 + ' - ' + str(n), 'a')
            f.write(str(post-pre) + "ms\n")
            f.close

            # Program2
            command[0] = './' + program2
            pre = time.time()
            call(command)
            post = time.time()
            f = open(program2 + ' - ' + str(n), 'a')
            f.write(str(post-pre) + "ms\n")
            f.close
```

Go:

```
package main

import "strconv"
import "os"

func merge(v []int, e int, m int, d int) {
    size := d-e+1
    B := make([]int, size)
    i := e
    j := m + 1
    k := 0
    for i <= m && j <= d {
        if v[i] <= v[j] {
            B[k] = v[i]
            k++
            i++
        } else {
            B[k] = v[j]
            k++
            j++
        }
    }
    for i <= m {
        B[k] = v[i]
        k++
        i++
    }
    for j <= d {
        B[k] = v[j]
        k++
        j++
    }
    for k := 0; k <= d-e; k++ {
        v[e+k] = B[k]
    }
}

func mergesort(v []int, e int, d int) {
    if e < d {
        m := (e+d)/2
        mergesort(v, e, m)
        mergesort(v, m+1, d)
        merge(v, e, m, d)
    }
}

func main() {
    v := make([]int, 0)
    args := os.Args
    for i := 1; i < len(args); i++ {
        f,_ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[i])
        v = append(v, f)
    }
    mergesort(v, 0, len(args) - 1)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... always check mark your chosen correct answer to reward the kind effort they have renderer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't in your Python, because the Go program gets the same error without being called from Python. In your `main` func, you are creating a slice called `v`, starting from argument position `1`, so excluding the name of the program:

```
for i := 1; i < len(args); i++ {
    f,_ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[i])
    v = append(v, f)
}
```

But then you're giving `mergesort` the length of `args`, not the length of `v`, so it's an off-by-one error as it's been told `v` has 1 more element than it actually does. Down the line the program tries to access an element of `v` that's beyond the end of the slice:

```
mergesort(v, 0, len(args) - 1)
```

Try `mergesort(v, 0, len(v) - 1)` in your main function, instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly! What a stupid error hahaha

Answer (score -3):

Try changing:

```
call(command)
```

to

```
call(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: The Go program has an error whether or not it's called from Python, so this can't be the issue.  `command` is a list, in the Python script, and `call` does take a list argument without `shell=True`